# I do not start rabbitmq on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, services, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq on ubuntu 20.04 but when I want start it i get the following result

```
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and when i run `service rabbitmq-server status` I get following result

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-10-16 13:26:23 +0330; 9s ago
    Process: 32352 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 32352 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Standing by"
```

and when I run `systemctl status rabbitmq-server` I get the following result

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Sun 2022-10-16 13:27:53 +0330; 55s ago
   Main PID: 32606 (beam.smp)
     Status: "Startup in progress"
      Tasks: 27 (limit: 18950)
     Memory: 41.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
             ├─32606 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-13.1.1/bin/beam.smp -W w -MBas ageffcbf -MHas ageffcbf -MBlmbcs 512 -MHlmbcs 512 -MMmcs 30 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -stbt db -zdbbl 128000 -sbwt none -sbwtdcpu none>
             ├─32616 erl_child_setup 32768
             ├─32672 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-13.1.1/bin/inet_gethost 4
             └─32673 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-13.1.1/bin/inet_gethost 4

اوْکتوْبر 16 13:27:53 elk.kifarunix-demo.com systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ broker...

[10]+  Stopped
```

this is my syslog

```
Oct 16 14:56:07 elk systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 18.
Oct 16 14:56:07 elk systemd[1]: Stopped RabbitMQ broker.
Oct 16 14:56:07 elk systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ broker...
Oct 16 14:56:32 elk openconnect[4192]: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:13.995976+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:13.995976+03:30 [error] <0.131.0> BOOT FAILED
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:13.995976+03:30 [error] <0.131.0> ===========
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:13.995976+03:30 [error] <0.131.0> ERROR: epmd error for host elk: timeout (timed out)
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:13.995976+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: BOOT FAILED
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: ===========
Oct 16 14:57:14 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: ERROR: epmd error for host elk: timeout (timed out)
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>     supervisor: {local,rabbit_prelaunch_sup}
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>     errorContext: start_error
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>     reason: {epmd_error,"elk",timeout}
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>                {id,prelaunch},
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>                {mfargs,{rabbit_prelaunch,run_prelaunch_first_phase,[]}},
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>                {restart_type,transient},
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>                {significant,false},
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>                {shutdown,5000},
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>                {child_type,worker}]
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.025277+03:30 [error] <0.131.0>
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>   crasher:
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     pid: <0.129.0>
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     registered_name: []
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     exception exit: {{shutdown,
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>                          {failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>                              {epmd_error,"elk",timeout}}},
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>                      {rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     ancestors: [<0.128.0>]
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     message_queue_len: 1
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     messages: [{'EXIT',<0.130.0>,normal}]
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     links: [<0.128.0>,<0.44.0>]
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     dictionary: []
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     trap_exit: true
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     status: running
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     heap_size: 376
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     stack_size: 28
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>     reductions: 175
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>   neighbours:
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.026099+03:30 [error] <0.129.0>
Oct 16 14:57:15 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: 2022-10-16 14:57:15.040319+03:30 [notice] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_prelaunch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{epmd_error,"elk",timeout}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
Oct 16 14:57:16 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{epmd_error,\"elk\",timeout}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Oct 16 14:57:16 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{epmd_error,"elk",timeout}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
Oct 16 14:57:16 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: #015
Oct 16 14:57:16 elk rabbitmq-server[48324]: Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
Oct 16 14:57:16 elk systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 16 14:57:16 elk systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 14:57:16 elk systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
Oct 16 14:57:26 elk systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 19.
Oct 16 14:57:26 elk systemd[1]: Stopped RabbitMQ broker.
Oct 16 14:57:26 elk systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ broker...
Oct 16 14:57:45 elk openconnect[4192]: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
```

how can i solve this problem?

thanks for your help

Comment: What tutorial and or commands did you use to install this app?

Comment: There may be some better information in `/var/log/syslog` to explain the failure 

Comment: https://lindevs.com/install-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu@David

Comment: I edited my question and put syslog info@matigo

Comment: Thank you very much@matigo, I checked the syslog and found out what the problem is

Comment: Crashes like this are considered a bug. File a bug report with rabbitmq, and attach the dump file to the bug report.